# Expand the cap for Community Specific Closure Reasons to 10

Tags: feature-request, custom-close-reasons

Currently the community is in the process of reviewing and modernizing the set of close reasons that Stack Overflow has available to use.

However, the current arbitrary cap of 5 community specific closure reasons is standing in the way of progress.

Closure can be a difficult process for edge cases, and often we end up with overlap in reasons which are currently designed to hit multiple scenarios as it is.

We need to decouple these reasons from each other in order to make the process more straightforward. This will help askers better understand what went wrong with their question, as well as helping the community at large better describe on and off topic questions.

**Please raise the cap of community specific closure reasons to 10**.

Comment: but 5 is such a neat number

Comment: 6 would definitely be helpful. 8, maybe. 10 is way too many, if you ask me.

Comment: This might be better with a concrete proposal of what we could do with ten.  Six: General computing, Recommendation request, Math/Statistics, Needs debugging details, Typo, Non-English.

Comment: The array of options is already dizzying. The biggest issue is not the "community-specific closure reasons", but rather the standard reasons that we're stuck with and cannot change or customize in any way. But, when combined, there are already too many options to choose from. Adding more will not help. I don't see any way in which the cap of 5 is standing in the way of progress.

Comment: You are right Cody, in that the entire set is problematic. At least with a community defined set, we could bypass that mess.

Answer (score 11):

Not going to outright decline this... but... no.

I understand the urge to just pull out all the stops and go to <s>11</s> 10 but that can have negative impacts that may not be immediately obvious.

We specifically set the limit at three (network-wide) because we want sites to be thoughtful about their close reasons and limit their use to situations that are actually high-volume. On a site that's as large as Stack Overflow and has so many types of user from around the technical and non-technical world, I can understand it can be difficult - if not impossible - to shove everything into three, or even five, reasons.

That's *why* we allow more close reasons when sites show need... but we also require them to define the new close reasons and show there's a need for the additional slot. We then review it and approve or reject the reason with an explanation and (if approved) let the mods take it from there.

But there is an additional reason we explicitly restrict the number of options - because **having too many options makes it harder to actually process the close action correctly**. The outcome can be various but it can include things like:

- Having too many options leaves close flaggers and voters unsure which option to pick from so many, so they give up and stop flagging/voting to close.
- Having too many options leaves close flaggers and voters unsure which option to pick so they just pick something random (and then likely get suspended from reviewing for picking the wrong thing).
- Having too many options makes it more likely that close votes will not be in agreement of which option should be used, meaning it's less clear to the asker what needs to be addressed.
- Having more options makes picking an option take longer ([Hick's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hick%27s_law)).

While it's not guaranteed, this feels like you could end up with a lot of people not helping with closing questions that need it and we're already shorthanded on that. In some cases, bigger buckets *simplify* the process for the person doing the sorting... that said, it can make it more difficult for the asker to know what the specific problem with their question is.

So, I do understand that there are upsides to this that should be considered when balancing the decision:

- More specific choices gives more specific guidance to askers whose questions are closed (assuming there's consensus).
- More specific choices can leave close flaggers and voters feeling more confident about their choices being understood and reduce some frustration about whether a comment should be added or not (because comments are less-necessary).
- More specific choices give additional room (in the UI) to explain the specific close reason.

There's probably others but that's what I could come up with as I was writing this.

So, in the end, I'm not saying no to adding any more reasons, I'm just saying no to adding a block of reasons without any thought put into what would fill those slots. Essentially, ask for slots one at a time and the CMs will review each request as it comes in.

Comment: If anything is done, I'd much rather it be letting us customize the top-level reasons. Some of those could be eliminated outright or at least replaced with *more specific* reasons that give more actionable advice for the purposes of Stack Overflow. I think that comes closer to addressing Travis J's primary concern/motivation, while not bloating the total number of close reasons, the concern you draw out here, which I agree strongly with.

Comment: Why would there have been no thought into each reason? Don't you think that if I were to define 5 new close reasons, with the history, timelines, and logic behind each one, that would have been a massive post? This simply raises the cap to allow for the community to begin work on making reasons that can succeed. At present, there are too many corners cut as it is with the reasons to fit into 5.